# ASP.net MVC HtmlHelper in VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

stupid question here.  I'm trying to create a helper method, something similar to the radio button list in the MVC futures project (as a learning tool).

I'm trying to convert the C# code:

```
 public static string[] RadioButtonList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) {
```

to a method signature in VB.net, but I'm not sure how to write the first parameter in VB.net, or what you would call this, so I could look it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work as long as you remember to mark it as an extension method, you could look up Extension Methods on [MSDN.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx). They have examples of how to write extension methods in VB.net.

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function RadioButtonList(ByVal htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, ByVal name As String, ByVal htmlAttributes As IDictionary(Of String, Object)) As String()
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not either.  But this is the signature of an extension method.  [Here's the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) on doing this in VB.

Answer (score 1):

They are called [Extension methods](http://www.developer.com/voice/article.php/3679651/Implementing-Extension-Methods-in-VBNET.htm), and are declared in VB.Net like this:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub RadioButtonList(ByVal name As String, ...)
// There's no "this" parameter at all...
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods in VB can only be declared from within a module, not a class, so a complete skeleton definition would look something like this...

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Public Module MyModule

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Function MyHelper (ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, MyParameter as String) As String

    End Function

End Module
```